# R, GET and GZ compression

Tags: r, rest, get, rcurl, gzip

I am building clients onto RESTful APIs.  Some links let me download attachments (files) from the server, and in the best case these are .txt.  I only mention the RESTful part since it means that I have to send some headers and potentially body with each post - the standard R 'filename'=URL logic won't work.

Sometimes people bundle many txts into a zip.  These are awkward since I don't know what they contain until I download many of them.

For the moment, I am unpackaging these, gzipping the files (adds the .gz extension) and re-uploading them.  They can then be indexed and downloaded.

I'm using Hadley's cute *httr* package, but I can't see an elegant way to decompress the gz files.

When using read.csv or similar any files with a gz ending are automatically decompressed (convenient!).  What's the equivalent when using httr or curl?

```
content(GET("http://glimmer.rstudio.com/alexbbrown/gz/sample.txt.gz"))
[1] 1f 8b 08 08 4e 9e 9b 51 00 03 73 ...
```

That looks nice, a compressed byte stream with the correct header (1f 8b).  Now I need the text contents, so I tried using memDecompress, which says it should do this:

```
memDecompress(content(GET("http://glimmer.rstudio.com/alexbbrown/gz/sample.txt.gz")),type="gzip")
Error in memDecompress(content(GET("http://glimmer.rstudio.com/alexbbrown/gz/sample.txt.gz")),  : 
  internal error -3 in memDecompress(2)
```

What's the proper solution here?

Also, is there a way to get R to pull the INDEX of a remote .zip file without downloading all of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a parser to handle the mime type. Look at `?content` and the line `You can add new parsers by adding appropriately functions to httr:::parser`

```
ls(httr:::parsers)

#[1] "application/json"                  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" #"image/jpeg"                       
#[4] "image/png"                         "text/html"                         #"text/plain"                       
#[7] "text/xml"
```

we can add one to handle `gz` content. I dont have a better answer at this point then you gave so you can incorporate your function.

```
assign("application/octet-stream", function(x, ...) {scan(gzcon(rawConnection(x)),"",,,"\n")},envir = httr:::parsers)

content(GET("http://glimmer.rstudio.com/alexbbrown/gz/sample.txt.gz"), as = "parsed")

Read 1 item
[1] "These are not the droids you are looking for"
>
```

EDIT:
I hacked together an alternative:

```
assign("application/octet-stream", function(x, ...) {f <- tempfile(); writeBin(x,f);untar(f);readLines(f, warn = FALSE)},envir = httr:::parsers)

content(GET("http://glimmer.rstudio.com/alexbbrown/gz/sample.txt.gz"), as = "parsed")
#[1] "These are not the droids you are looking for"
```

With regards to listing the files in the archive maybe you can adjust the function somewhat.
If we try to get the `httr` source files.  They have a mime type "application/x-gzip"

```
assign("application/x-gzip", function(x, ...) {
    f <- tempfile(); 
    writeBin(x,f); 
    if(!is.null(list(...)$list)){
        if(list(...)$list){
            return(untar(f, list = TRUE))
        }else{
            untar(f, ...);
            readLines(f)
        }
    }else{
        untar(f, ...);
        readLines(f)
    }
}, envir = httr:::parsers)

content(GET("http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/httr_0.2.tar.gz"), as = "parsed", list = TRUE)

# > head(content(GET("http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/httr_0.2.tar.gz"), as = "parsed", list = TRUE))
#[1] "httr/"                 "httr/MD5"              "httr/tests/"          
#[4] "httr/tests/test-all.R" "httr/README.md"        "httr/R/"
```

Comment: Great stuff!  As far as getting the INDEX I really would like to read the index without downloading, I think that's going to require partial gets etc.  I doubt R incorporates a zip decoder that uses seeks that could just read the index.  May have to write myself.

Answer (score 5):

The following works, but seems a little convoluted:

```
> scan(gzcon(rawConnection(content(GET("http://glimmer.rstudio.com/alexbbrown/gz/sample.txt.gz")))),"",,,"\n")
Read 1 item
[1] "These are not the droids you are looking for"
```